# browserstack+nightwatch custom commands configuration

Tags: json, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I have a Nightwatch + BrowserStack configuration on my project and I'm trying to add custom commands to my project to compare 2 screenshots using resemble.js .
I configure my `nightwatch.json` file with this :

```
"custom_commands_path": "./node_modules/nightwatch/commands",
"custom_assertions_path": "./node_modules/nightwatch/assertions"
```

I put the commands file in the folder and I tried to run my test in every directory possible to see if it was a path problem. I've also tried with different commands, some of them I get online and even the default example one. Whatever I run it returns `nameOfTheCommand is not a function`. So I guess it does not even find the path to the customs commands in the nightwatch.json file.
Is there anything I'm missing here? I'm quite new so the answer could be very simple but I tried every .json file of my project in case there was a special configuration linked to BrowserStack.

Answer (score 0):

Path to the custom commands should be analogous to the path to custom commands. You should point a folder where you added them.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if I put them in the suite configuration file, it picks them up:

```
nightwatch_config = {
    src_folders: ["tests/suite/product/"],
    page_objects_path: "pages/product",
    custom_commands_path: "./custom_commands"
}
```